# Fill in calculated variables for rows added to a data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I've added rows to a complex data frame and the new records are missing some computed variables. The only way I can currently fix this is to remove the rows, create a new variable, and then reattach, but I know there must be a better way. For this example, I expect I'll need to pass the age variable through some if else statements to calculate age category. Looking for the least disruptive way to do this in the data frame.

```
name <- c("mina", "alex", "katie", "eric")
age <- c(66, 24, 19, 36)
age_category <- c("65+", "18 to 29", NA, NA)
test <- data.frame(name, age, age_category)

test
   name age age_category
1  mina  66          "65+"
2  alex  24     "18 to 29"
3 katie  19         <NA>
3  eric  36         <NA>
```

Hope this is not too obvious a question! Could not find it on here easily. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can use [cut](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/cut). Something like `cut(age, breaks = c(-Inf, 18, 29, 65, Inf), labels = c('less than 18', '18 to 29', '29 to 65', 'more than 65'))`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, glad to know about this cool function. I believe this is not the best use case for it because I am trying to avoid factors. I am manipulating a table for future use in Stata. I should have specified this in the question, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but how about `dplyr::case_when`? Also, not sure `age = 36`'s category should be.

```
library(dplyr)

test %>%
  mutate(age_category = case_when(
    65 <= age ~ "65+",
    18 <= age & age < 29 ~ "18 to 29",
    29 <= age & age < 40 ~ "29 to 40",
    TRUE ~ "I don't know"
  ))

   name age age_category
1  mina  66          65+
2  alex  24     18 to 29
3 katie  19     18 to 29
4  eric  36     29 to 40
```